# Redirect url are not the correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a MVC 4 project with a user login page.  It all works fine.

The issue is when i click on the link to log out, the redirect URL is incorrect.

Here is the code to explain better:

**View:**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")">Logout ?</a>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
  {
     WebSecurity.Logout();

      return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
  }
```

When I click on the log out link, the URL show me this ==> `Account/LogOff`

But I want to redirect to this ==> `Account/Login`

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: This should be HttpGet request AFAIK, remove HttpPost attribute. Does it redirect you to correct webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML an anchor element (`<a>`) sends GET request, not POST, so your `[HttpPost]` controller action will never be invoked. You should use an HTML form with POST method if you want to invoke this action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit">Logout ?</button>
}
```

Also notice that I included an AntiForgery token inside the form because your controller action is decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute and thus is expecting it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove HttpPost attribute and everything should be fine.

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
  {
     WebSecurity.Logout();

      return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
  }
```